# Loading dependent DLLs from Azure Blob

Tags: dynamic, dll, azure, blob, loading

I'm using a plugin architecture on Windows Azure. In order to survive restarts, I want to store the plugin DLLs in a blob rather than in the file system. However, I run into problems with dependencies between the DLLs. I have the following situation:

- DLL A is dependent on DLL B
- Both are stored in an Azure Blob
- I first load DLL B, no problems there
- I then try to load DLL A - Exception that it cannot find the file containing DLL B

It is of course very logical, as DLL B is not in the local file system. Is there any way of getting the class loader to not try to load DLL B but rather look in memory as it is already loaded? Or do I need to go back and revise the design.

Comment: can you explain how you're loading the plugins? Who is actually loading your DLLs? You? a Framework? Also, where are those dlls stored? local folder? GAC?

Comment: btw, are you using IaaS or PaaS?

Comment: Seems like you are not using Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) Or Managed AddIn Framework (MAF or System.AddIn) - Even if you are, you might need to download blobs to a directory on your role before loading.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest pattern is to use the On_Start function (or startup script) to copy both DLLs to a known local location during role initialization.